# TableView doesn't show my Data from Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, tableview, cell

i have one problem: my tableView doesn't show any data from realm database. But i guess the problem is in cell.

```
class ClientViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    var clientsInfo: Results<Client> {
        get {
            return realm.objects(Client.self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.reloadData()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! myCell
        let info=clientsInfo[indexPath.row]
        cell.todoLabel.text = info.firstName
        return cell

    }
}

class myCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    static let reuseIdentifier = "cell"


    @IBOutlet weak var todoLabel: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used a lazy property for Realm results on a View Controller that way before. What I usually do is to keep a variable on the controller `private var clientsInfo: Results<Client>?`. On the `viewDidLoad` function perform your query so the object gets defined: `self.clientsInfo = realm.objects(...)`. 
On the table view datasource methods you can call that `clientsInfo` variable. It is efficient because the Realm queries are lazy, so no objects are loaded unless necessary.

Comment: A computed variable as data source array is horribly expensive especially when data is fetched from a database. **Don't do that**.

Answer (score 2):

There is a few things wrong in your code,

**First:**

You're using a UITableViewController, by default this already has a tableView, so you don't need to declare a new tableView like you did

```
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
```

**Second:**

In you viewDidLoad you're registering the cell for the default tableView and using your declared table for dataSource and delegate, this won't work. I recommend you remove the table you create and use the default so your viewDidLoad would look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(myCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

**and Third:**

you're missing the implementation of :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you forgot to implement `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection:)` method, so it returns 0 by default and your `tableview(cellForRowAt:)` method never called.

**AND**

Maybe this is not about your question but;

You used `UITableView` variable(name is ***table***) in `UITableView`. It's unneccessary, because UITableView already has a UITableView(name is ***tableView***). And you'have registered your cell into **tableView**, but it seems you try to dequeue this cell from ***table***.